# Convert non-English text into readable format

Tags: c#, .net, language-features

I am obtaining strings from the web which often contain accented characters not recognised from within my application.

**Edit** - I'm obtaining my string using the HtmlAgilityPack. I am taking the `InnerText` of a `<title>` tag. Whilst doing this the Pack uses a different encoding from the original HTML document (I'm not sure which ones though?).

```
        // get the html title inner text and assign to htmlParts object
        HtmlNode titleNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//title");
        string docTitle = titleNode.InnerText;
        htmlParts.htmlTitle = docTitle.ToString();
```

Can anyone tell me how I can go from getting `"(Subtitulado al espaÃ±ol).avi"` to `"(Subtitulado al español).avi"` ?

I'd very much appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're getting UTF-8, but processing it as ISO-8859-1.

It's not possible to give more concrete information without knowing more about your system.

Comment: Michael, can you explain how you did the encoding? I'm still have problems with this.

Comment: @TysHTTP: If you're asking how to do the actual transformation, there are methods in .NET to convert from one encoding to another (check the [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) class). If you're asking how I could identify them, it's all about the exact characters in the OP.

Comment: I now did it like this, and this works fine: HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb(); web.OverrideEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

Answer (score 0):

apply proper encoding to the data you read. How exactly? Good question. For that you at least need to provide the code that causes the problem in the first place.